# Allow 0 quantity on Woocommerce Line Order

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to allow 0 quantity on Woocommerce Line order when edit. 
Currently it will automatically remove when it is 0.
Kindly advise.
Thanks.

Comment: That is not possible, as Zero quantity is just like removing your item (just like in cart)…

Comment: Thanks. Anyway for us to change the product title without removing the previous product?